# Is "with" optional after "conferring"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Consider the sentence:

> I answered the question as a novice, without conferring with Sir Thomas More or Sir Francis Bacon.

Is the *with* optional?  Could the sentence also be written as:

> I answered the question as a novice, without conferring Sir Thomas More or Sir Francis Bacon.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are thinking of 'consult' or 'consult with'? Either of these is possible in the examples you gave. You can say that two people conferred, or that one person conferred with another.

Confer has two meanings:

> **Confer (with)**
>   to exchange ideas on a particular subject, often in order to reach a decision on what action to take:
>
> I need some time to confer **with** my lawyer.
>
> **Confer (on or upon)**
>   to give an official title, honour, or advantage to someone:
>
> An honorary doctorate was conferred **on** him by Columbia University.

[Confer (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confer)

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  In this context, think of *consult* as seeking advice (e.g., from an expert) and *confer* to have discussions more as equals.  Does this sound right to you?  Please excuse the "novice" and who the people are as I now realize that may confuse the context of "confer", but I still intended it as a discussion of opinion.  Regarding my initial question, I suppose my confusion is using the present participle of *confer* followed by the pronouns / *subject complements(?)*

Comment: Yes, we generally consult experts, and confer with equals.

Comment: The second definition is obviously not relevant to the question and only serves to confuse (me if nobody else). I recommend you remove it.

Comment: It has stood for 10 months; it can remain.